# What do the icons under 'links' in Adobe AI mean?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

I am opening an Adobe AI file that was sent to me and created by someone else that contains missing links.  What does this icon mean?

[image]

I am assuming it's something along the lines of the asset not being found in Adobe CC assets / cloud or something?

Comment: I think your assumption is most likely the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud icon shows that the image was placed using a Cloud-based CC Library asset.  I would assume that the red circle means that you don't have access to that particular CC Library.